# Wrapper library/client for Cassandra to get space usage by column family

Tags: cassandra

Want to write report that print storage /pace used by each column family in a keyspace.

I explored pycassa, but could not find library that let me get column family statistics like space used . I know nodettol cfstats has the information that I am looking for but couldn't find client library that will help me get that information.

Should I use python and cql ?
should I write shell wrapper for nodetool?
any alternative

Help or recommendation is appreciated.